# How can I use cmake to compile multiple source files and generate multiple executable files named after these file names

Tags: c++, cmake

Currently, I need help either creating a `CMakeList.txt`, or simply figuring out the `cmake` command for the following.

I have some source files in the same directory, called `A.cpp`, `B.cpp`, `C.cpp`, `D.cpp`. I need to compile these such that the executables are named as A, B, C, D, respectively.

I want to use `CMake` to automatically traverse the directory and generate the corresponding executable file instead of adding the corresponding executable file in `CMakeList.txt` every time I add a file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bit of an odd request. Usually I'd suggest manually writing `add_executable` where needed since it's more maintainable.

In CMake, there isn't really a *good* way to collect all files in a directory. You can use `file(GLOB ...)` to grab all files; but this gets done at *configure* time, and if you introduce new sources then CMake won't detect the new source and won't reconfigure automatically or build the new sources without explicitly being told to reconfigure.

If you're able to discretely list each source, it would be better. But otherwise what you are requesting can be done with a combination of a `foreach` through each source file using [`get_filename_component`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/get_filename_component.html) to get the file name and passing it to [`add_executable`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_executable.html)

```
set(source_files src/a.cpp src/b.cpp src/c.cpp ...)

# Loop through each source file
foreach(source_file IN LISTS source_files)
    # Get the name of the file without the extension (e.g. 'a' from src/a.cpp'
    get_filename_component(target_name ${source_file} NAME_WE)
    
    # Create an executable with the above name, building the above source
    add_executable("${target_name}" "${source_file}"
endforeach()
```

If discretely listing the source files isn't possible, you can use [`file(GLOB...)` or `file(GLOB_RECURSE)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html):

```
file(GLOB source_files "src/*.cpp")
```

But again; this prevents automatically detecting when new sources get added, and I don't recommend it.

Comment: Through `foreach` I achieved the result I wanted, and later I will pay attention to the impact  of `file(GLOB...)` you mentioned.Thank you for your answer sincerely.